# Setting up localhost receiving error "You don't have permission to access /C: on this server"

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, localhost, wamp

I can reach localhost and phpmyadmin but cant reach directory where are my projects.

```
localhost/C:/wamp/www  ===> You don't have permission to access /C: on this server.
```

Comment: I'd think that, if your index.html is at c:\wamp\www you can just go to localhost. If your index.html is at c:\wamp\www\mySite you can just go to localhost/mySite

Comment: @Dobromir, try to add a little more details to your question. What are you trying to exactly or at least add a little more info

Answer (score 0):

Look at your Apache config file http.conf

Inside that file you should find a line similar to:

DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Group/Apache/htdocs"

The DocumentRoot of your Apache server is where it looks when you request "localhost."  Make sure your projects are in the DocumentRoot.  For example copy your projects to, "C:/Program Files/Apache Group/Apache/htdocs/projects" then query your server at //localhost/projects/yourproject.php

Answer (score 0):

In http.conf change Allow from 127.0.0.1 to Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\wamp ,right click on "www" folder,click the "security" tab ,click on "edit".In the "Group or user names" textbox/section,pick "your login name" and check "Full control".Click ok when you through.

OR

Type in "127.0.0.1" without the quote in your browser

Remember to "Mark/Tick" if this solve your problem